# Axios: How to get the error code in case of an "Network Error"?

Tags: node.js, axios, jestjs, ts-jest

I want to test an axios post call that should reject with an "ECONNREFUSED" in case the server is not running.

```
const promise= axios.post("/path/under/test", {"some":"data"});
await expect(promise).rejects.toThrowError("ECONNREFUSED");
```

Unfortunatly the error contains a very generic "Network Error" message in the test. I can see in the console output that "some where" the expected code "ECONNREFUSED" is part of the root error. But how to get the error code?

this is how the "stringyfied" Error looks like:

```
{"message":"Network Error","name":"Error","stack":"[...]"
```

Comment: `toThrowError` should match when error message includes the substring. So if `ECONNREFUSED` is somewhere in the error should pass. Also try using `RegEx`: `toThrowError(/ECONNREFUSED/);`

Comment: The problem is no error code is included in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**

The simplified message "Network Error" is shown because Axios assumes during tests it runs in the browser. For security reasons all I/O releated errors are reduced to this message, it is only possible to distinguish specific errors when Axios assumes to run in Node.

**Solution**

All error codes will be included when the following is imported in the test file. It makes Axios assume to run in Node. This also help to avoid CORS issues.

```
axios.defaults.adapter = require("axios/lib/adapters/http");
```